# Getting Frequent DecisionTaskTimeout

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am getting started with SWF and following the Hello World tutorial here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/getting-started-example-helloworldworkflow.html

The only difference is that I am using Spring to set up the Activity and Workflow workers as well as the workflow executor as seen here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/test.html. My workflow starts up fine and I can see the execution in my AWS console. However, I am getting almost constant DecisionTaskTimeouts and Activities are not starting often. I have confirmed that the Activities are registered. What could be causing the timeouts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DecisionTaskTimeout happens when decision task is picked up by a worker but not completed in the configured interval. First check the configured timeout on the workflow type. If is not too low the probable cause is some problem with your decider that causes task not to complete. I would recommend enabling DEBUG level of logging to get more info about decider execution.